# Can I make an android game on local wireless network?

Tags: java, android, jmdns

I want to develop a game (mastermind) on android. I want to create a game server online but if two devices are in the same local wireless network I would like for them to play via the local network and not trough the online server.  For the server part I am thinking to use java and TCP sockets with java object serialization and regarding the fact that I want the players to use the local wireless network if possible I read something about JmDNS. At this point I am only in an early developmental stage and I would like to know if this is possible. Also, I was hoping you could provide me with some resources to get started and point me in the right direction. 
Thanks.

Comment: stack overflow is not the right forum for your request

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all you should be able to build web based and Network based game seperatly, then try integrating this, first look for network and then web.